# Why does 'puts Time' have a string output of "Time"

Tags: ruby, class, output, puts

If you run the following:

```
puts Time
```

Then the output is as follows;

```
Time
```

Which strikes me as odd, but I can't yet figure out why, the same applies to `Class`, and `Method`.

I can see that these are classes, but why would Ruby output them to the console?

Comment: it seems to print the class name of the class. Since Time is a class, it prints the name. Probably since all classes by default respond to to_s, so classname.to_s is that classname.

Comment: What was your expectation when you wrote `puts Time` ?

Comment: To be honest I just did it by mistake and was intrigued by the result. But I didn't expect "Time" as an output. The comments here have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, everything in ruby is an object. In your case Time is an object of Class. You can find out it by

```
Time.class  => Class
```

If you pass it to  puts or p then it simply run inspect method on it. so you can get same output Time and Time.inspect

```
puts Time = puts Time.inspect
```

Would like to explain bit better. Assume you have a class

```
class A
end
```

now run the following and observer the output

```
puts A
puts A.inspect
puts A.new
puts A.new.inpsect
```

Answer (score 5):

The classes `Time`, `Class`, `Method`, etc, are themselves instances of the class `Class`.

```
Time.class
# => Class
```

`Class` inherites `to_s` from [`Module#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-to_s), which is the name of the class:

```
Time.to_s
# => "Time"
```

When you execute `puts Time`, `Time` is converted to a string by `to_s`, therefore the result.